# What is better msxsl:node-set() or exsl:node-set() function?

Tags: c#, .net, performance, xslt

I have a big troubles with performance and memory usage during XSLT transformation. I have browse several pages how to optimize XSLT and one of the ways is to reduce usage of `node-set()` function.

I have found that there are two functions of node-set in `msxsl` and `exsl`. Are these functions different in performace and memory usage?

Comment: Are you using XSLT 1.0 or 2.0 ? Because in 2.0 there is no need to use node-set anymore.

Comment: .NET does not support XPath/XSLT 2.0., I'm using XSLT 1.0

Comment: Ahh doh!... is it possible for you to consider using a 3rd party open source implementation such as http://saxon.sourceforge.net/ ?

Comment: I will investigate 3rd party components..

Answer (score 1):

Pure XSLT 1.0 does not provide a way to convert a result tree fragment into a node set so an XSLT 1.0 processor has to offer an extension function for that task. The various versions of Microsoft's MSXML processor offer one with local name `node-set` in the namespace `urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt` and the documentation and many examples tie that namespace to the prefix `msxsl` so that the usage examples then call `msxsl:node-set($rtf-var)`. You could use any other prefix however, what matters is the namespace and MSXML only works with the namespace `urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt`.

As fas as I know, in the .NET framework the `XslTransform` class (now obsolete) also only supports the extension function `node-set` in that Microsoft namespace `` `urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt ``.

However as the EXSLT iniative standardized an extension function named `node-set` in the namespace `http://exslt.org/common` many XSLT processors by now offer support for that EXSLT extension function which is usually called as `exsl:node-set` but again what matters is the namespace and not the prefix. Microsoft's `XslCompiledTransform` in the .NET framework supports both extension function namespaces for a `node-set` function so there you have a choice. There is no difference in the functionality and I am not aware of any performance difference and I don't think there is one as I can't imagine why a different name should lead to a different, more complex implementation.

I would rather consider which compatibility you need for your stylesheet, if you want to run it with .NET and with MSXML (e.g. inside of Internet Explorer), then choose the namespace `urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt`, if you want to run it with .NET and perhaps with XSLT processors on other platforms then the EXSLT namespace gives you better compatibility.

Even MSXML can be "convinced" to support the `node-set` function in the EXSLT namespace by making use of a simple extension function script done in JScript or VBScript but that approach then could result in a performance penalty as the XSLT processor has to load the script engine.

Answer (score 1):

You've given no information as to why you think the node-set() function has anything to do with your performance problems. In fact you've given us no information about the nature of your transformation, the performance measurements you have made, or the technology you are using. All you've told us is that you've googled for possible causes of performance problems and you're exploring one of them.

You need to be much more systematic. Start by measuring how the performance (time and memory) changes with increasing data size; the graph will tell us a lot. Use profiling tools such as Saxon's -TP to see where the time is going. Simply testing how the performance varies with different processors might be instructive. Basically, you need data before you start coming up with theories.

Answer (score 0):

I wonder why you are using node-set at all... [Taken from this 12 year old post](http://www.xml.com/pub/a/2002/04/10/xslt2.html)

"If you haven't guessed already, XSLT 2.0 has shown RTFs the door. Now when you use xsl:variable to create a temporary tree, the value of that variable is a true node-set. Actually, in XPath 2.0 terms, it is a true node sequence, consisting of one document node, which is XPath 2.0's name for what XPath 1.0 called a "root node". With that sequence you can then use path expressions to drill down inside the tree, apply templates to it, and so on, just like you would with any other source document. With XSLT 2.0, there is no longer a need for the node-set() extension function."